# Why is 'The apple is 3 yuan' written '苹果三块' and not '苹果是三块'

Tags: simplified-characters

Why is 'The apple is 3 yuan' written '苹果三块' and not '苹果是三块', or are both acceptable?

Comment: Both are fine. Which source did you find the phrase?

Comment: HelloChinese mobile app.

Comment: I'd say it's analogous to how people write recipe in English: Sugar 2 tbsp. It's not really a sentence since it lacks the verb.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both acceptable:

'**苹果三块**' (apple, three yuans) --> short for:  '苹果(的价格是)三块（一个/一磅)'

'**苹果是三块** (Apple is three yuans) --> short: for '苹果(的价格)是三块（一个/一磅)'

Both mean 'the price of the apple is three yuans (each/ a pound)

苹果是三块 is kind of wordy for a length reduced sentence, therefore, 苹果三块 is the preferred way to shorten 苹果的价格是三块一个 or 苹果賣三块一个

No one would interpret 苹果是三块 as 苹果 can be used as a currency for three yuans